# GitLab login problems when using iCloud Private Relay

Tags: gitlab

I'm using **iCloud Private Relay** and I have to sign in to GitLab every single day again and again, even when ticking the checkbox "remember me".

After digging into the settings, I was able to find all the active sessions and there were a dozens of them with different IP addresses.

It seems to me that GitLab isn't able to handle changing IP addresses. Never experienced something similar like GitLab with another website so I'm wondering if I'm doing something wrong?